# Can not insert Data to table with a foreign key to a IdentityColumn, in ef core 2

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

## Problem

I can not insert Data to a sql table with a foreign key to a IdentityColumn, in ef core 2.

## Setup:

I have the following Entitie classes:

```cs
public class CourseMeeting
{
   public int MID{ get; set; }
   public int CID { get; set; }
   public Course Course { get; set; }
   public DateTime DateOfTheMeeting { get; set; }  
   public int MaxParticipants { get; set; }
   public IList<CourseMeetingParticipant> CourseMeetingParticipants {get;set;}
   }

public class CourseMeetingParticipant
{
   public int MID{ get; set; }
   public CourseMeeting CourseMeeting { get; set; }
   public string SUID { get; set; }
   public User Student { get; set; }
}
```

I map the classes to two SQL-Server tables with the Fluent API:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<CourseMeeting>(cm =>
{
    cm.HasKey(k => k.MID);

    cm.Property(p => p.MID)
        .UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();

    cm.HasMany(m => m.CourseMeetingParticipants)
        .WithOne(m => m.CourseMeeting);
});


modelBuilder.Entity<CourseMeetingParticipant>(c =>
{

c.HasOne(m => m.CourseMeeting)
      .WithMany(m => m.CourseMeetingParticipants)
      .HasForeignKey(k => k.MID)
      .HasPrincipalKey(p => p.MID);

c.Property(p => p.MID);

c.HasKey(k => new {k.MID, k.SUID});
});
```

The Tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CourseMeetingParticipants](
    [MID] [int] NULL,
    [SUID] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CourseMeetingParticipants]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([MID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CourseMeetings] ([MID])

alter table [dbo].[CourseMeetingParticipants]
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CP PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (MID, SUID);  

go
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CourseMeetings]
(
    [MID] INT IDENTITY(0,1) PRIMARY KEY
   ,[CID] INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Courses (CID)
   ,[DateOfTheMeeting] datetime2 not null
   ,[MaxParticipants] int not null
)
```

When I try to add CourseMeetingParticipant to the table CourseMeetingParticipants I get the following Error:

InvalidOperationException: The property 'MID' on entity type 'CourseMeetingParticipant' has a temporary value. Either set a permanent value explicitly or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.

This is the method I use to add the CourseMeetingParticipant:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "Student")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SignInToCourseMeeting(int id){
    var participant = new CourseMeetingParticipant{
        MID = id,
        SUID = await _UserManger.GetUserIdAsync(await _UserManger.GetUserAsync(User)),
    };
    _db.CourseMeetingParticipants.Add(participant);
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Redirect("/Course/Courses");
 }
```

If i remove the HasOne, WithOne relations between the two entities i can add the CourseMeetingParticipant to the table with no problems. But in need the relations in other part of my Application. Have you any idea why this is not working?

Configuration:
ASP.NET Core 2.1

Answer (score 0):

You already have the relationship for `CourseMeeting` <--> `CourseMeetingParticipant` defined in your `CourseMeeting` entity. What if you remove the redundant definition from `CourseMeetingParticipant`?

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CourseMeetingParticipant>(c =>
{
    c.Property(p => p.MID);
    c.HasKey(k => new {k.MID, k.SUID});
});
```

It may also make sense for you to make `CourseMeetingParticipants.MID` non-nullable. Then your table would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CourseMeetingParticipants](
    [MID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SUID] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

and your `CourseMeeting` entity would have a required property:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CourseMeeting>(cm =>
{
    cm.HasKey(k => k.MID);

    cm.Property(p => p.MID)
        .UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();

    cm.HasMany(m => m.CourseMeetingParticipants)
        .WithRequired(m => m.CourseMeeting);
});
```

Comment: Thank your suggestions, but it does not work either.